# How to move text in a display block div

Tags: html, css

```css
.score{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.score p span{
    padding-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="score">
        <p>bb<span id="correctAns">jkjh </span></p>
    </div>
```

I want to move my text down a little bit but it's not working, putting padding in .score just makes it bigger and nothing happens if I put it in .score p span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nepotech's answer is correct. An other way is useing `line-height` for `.score`:

```css
.score {
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  width: 700px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">
  <p>bb<span id="correctAns">jkjh </span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Just Use `margin-top` to `p` element

- Note: I have changed color to `blue`, for better understanding!

```css
.score{
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
p{
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="score">
        <p>bb<span id="correctAns">jkjh </span></p>
    </div>
```

Comment: I copied your code, I even see it's working for you in the snippet but I don't know why it's not working for me.

Comment: @kiro that's okay, it varies for situations